# Java. Изменить название класса динамически из String

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть некий класс `Contakt.class`, но названия не имеет значение так как классов много, суть в том что вместо `Contakt` нужно подставить динамически другие значения.

Я получаю данные `text` и вставляю их в строку `String q2=text;` далее у меня есть код где есть `Contakt.class`, но вместо `Contakt` нужно вставить `q2`, где и храняться названия других классов.

Получится  что-то вроде `q2.class`, где вместо `q2` будут различные значения.

Есть ли такая возможность на Java?

Comment: Простите, но какая взаимосвязь заголовка и вопроса? 
В вопросе вы имеете ввиду модульную загрузку классов?

Это не плохо описано по следующим статьям:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/103830/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/104229/

Comment: Я не знаю как озаглавить вопрос, вначале думал, что можно просто убрать ковычки со String и можно будет вставлять. Сейчас уже понял, что нет

Comment: По-идеии вам нужен Class.forName(), гляньте тут https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_forname.htm .

Comment: @KirillStoianov, оформите ваш комментарий, как ответ, добавьте простой пример, и будет вам репутация!

Comment: Спасибо все за помошь, но я понял, что это не то что я искал. Сейчас я создал новый вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью методов `Class.forName()` и `newInstance()` объекта `Class` можно динамически загружать и создавать экземпляры класса в случае, когда имя класса неизвестно до момента выполнения программы.

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.xyz.MyClass"); 
Object obj = c.newInstance(); 
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) obj;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, но я неправильно сам вопрос создал
Сейчас его переписал

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572921/android-%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Решения я нашел, но это всетаки не-то, что нужно было

```
    try {
        // returns the Class object for the class with the specified name
         cls = Class.forName("net.artsait.bukvitsa."+bukvica);
        name100 =  cls.getSimpleName();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Сейчас я написал новый вопрос

[Android. Динамически поменять названия класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572921/android-%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)