# Android. Динамически поменять названия класса

Tags: java, android, строки, arraylist

Здравствуйте! У меня есть несколько моделей данных

```
public class А extends SugarRecord {
String А;
// пустой конструктор
public А() {
}

public А(String а) {
    this.А = а;
}
}
```

Такие же есть модели на `B, C` и так далее.

В фрагменте `FourFragment.java` я получаю эти модели

```
A contakt;
B contact2;
```

и далее

Содержимым в  `А` я заполняю `ArrayList`, ну и позже их вывожу в списке

```
        List<А> allCont = А.listAll(А.class);
    ArrayList<CharSequence> arrTitle4 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(А сontact2:allCont){
        arrTitle4.add(сontact2.А);
    }
```

Из Активити я получаю некие данные

```
        // получаем объект из активити
    if(getArguments() != null) {
        MyObject obj = getArguments().getParcelable("key");
        String buk =  obj.paramBukv;
    }
```

В `buk` в зависимости от неких условий будут разные данные, например получил B

Можно ли теперь в списке везде вместо A вставить содержимое `buk`

```
        List<А> allCont = А.listAll(А.class);
    ArrayList<CharSequence> arrTitle4 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(А сontact2:allCont){
        arrTitle4.add(сontact2.А);
    }
```

Другими словами

В ArrayList arrTitle4 заполнить значениями из одной модели данных, название которое будет совпадать со значением которое в buk. Например в buk я получил С, значит arrTitle4 будет заполняться из модели данных C.class. Можно ли так сделать?

Приложение работает таким образом, что при нажатии на пункт списка, открывается второе активити где есть несколько фрагментов, в первом фрагменте  идет просто описания и еще некоторые данные, а во втором фрагменте можно будет добавлять свои данные, которые будут выводиться в списке, но в каждом пункте будут свои списки.

Я для каждого пункта создал свою таблицу в БД, использую sugar ORM.
Соответственно сейчас у меня есть A.java, B.java и так далее.

Также есть строки A, B, C и т.д. Так вот я нажал на пункт например B, второе активити получило эту букву, передало во фрагмент в виде String buk; и сейчас как-то нужно добавить значение введенные пользователем в таблицу B и вывести все, что он ввел из БД, но он может нажать и на другой пункт например C. Поэтому я и хочу связать то что в buk с классом.

Я понимаю, что я явно пошел неправильным путем, но решения подобных задач нигде не нашел

Само приложение https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.artsait.bukvitsa

Comment: чтобы список `allCont` содержал не объекты типа `А`, а объекты типа, название которого записано в `buk `?

Comment: Попробуйте создать interface заимплиментить этот interface во всех объектах которые вы храните в списке, и сделайте этот список типизированым типа ArrayList<MyInterface>, таким образом объекты разных  классов сможете хранить в одном списке

Comment: Или можете попробовать не создавать interface  , а имплементировать java.io.Serializable и хранить все объекты в списке ArrayList<Serializible>

Comment: Да, вместо А было то, что записано в buk

Comment: С интерфейсом пока плоха знаком, вначале попробую разобраться как им пользоваться. А как их связать с buk?

Answer (score 3):

Что именно вы хотите сделать?

- Если получить объект из списка и заменить его филды какими то конкретными значениями? Да это реально сделать.
- Если добавить в список объектов `List<A> listAll` объект `B` это тоже можно сделать, для этого нужно чтобы классы `A` и `B`, которые вы будете добавлять в одни список имели общее поведение, тоесть или **имплементировали** один интерфейс, или были **наследниками** одного супер класса.

---

```
public interface Fish {
    void swip();
}

class A implements Fish {
//override methods
}

class B implements Fish {
//override methods
}
```

Теперь можно использовать общий контейнер для обеих типов классов.

```
List<Fish> bukAndA = new ArrayList<Fish>();
//добавляем объекты в коллекцию
bykAndA.add(new A());
bykAndA.add(new B());
```

Тоже самое и с наследованием суперкласса.

```
class Fish {
   void methodA(){//common logic};
}

class A extends Fish {
void methodA(){//specific logic};
}

class B extends Fish {
    void methodA(){//specific logic};
    }
```

В результате:

```
List<Fish> bukAndA = new ArrayList<Fish>();
//добавляем объекты в коллекцию
    bykAndA.add(new A());
    bykAndA.add(new B());
```

Тоесть у классов должно быть **общее поведение**.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, но результат немного другой будет. Я допишу вопрос, сложно правильно сформировать вопрос

Comment: В ArrayList arrTitle4 заполнить значениями из одной модели данных, название которое будет совпадать со значением которое в buk. Например в buk я получил С, значит arrTitle4 будет заполняться из модели данных C.class. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: поподробней пожалуйста

Comment: Если другими словами, нужно заполнить таблицу БД и вывести её в списке. Использую я Sugar ORM.
Для того  чтобы записать в таблицу БД, пишу такой код                 B contact2 = new B("текст");
                contact2.save(); Для того чтобы удалить из таблицы пишу следующий код                 B сontact = .findById(B.class, 1);
                сontact.delete();, но дело в том, что и в первом и во втором случае я работаю с таблицей B, а нужно чтобы динамически вместо B подставлялись другие значения.

Comment: Например в String buk; приходят данные, это может быть как A, B, C в зависимости от того что нажал пользователь. Так можно в Java вместо B к примеру в этом коде B contact2 = new B("текст"); contact2.save(); ставить значения из buk. Примерно так buk contact2 = new buk("текст"); , но buk  в данном случаем это String, поэтому ничего не выйдет, может его можно как-то конвертировать? Вы еще написали про филды, может их как-то можно здесь испоьзовать?

Comment: Всегда пишите названия классов с большой буквы.

чтобы динамически менять класс Class вам нужны generics; тоесть class BaseDao<T> { BaseDao(Class clazz){this.clazz = clazz}} и далее findById(Long id){return getEntityById(clazz, id)}

Comment: Я нашел статью http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/generic.php это Вы об этом говорите?

Comment: Да, и типом T может быть любой класс. напр Buk.class или  Sugar.class

Comment: Я понял. Сейчас попробую разобраться. Спасибо Вам большое

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста. Я создал класс class BaseDao<T> {
    Class clazz;
    BaseDao(Class clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

А где записать код findById(Long id){return getEntityById(clazz, id)}? Куда его и что он делает?

Comment: смотри например у тебя есть dao которое будет работать с buk, а есть также dao которое будет работать с класcом Animal, но метод тебе нужен один, T findById(Long id), который будет возвращать разные типы объектов, я правильно понимаю?